# Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which return

```
SELECT * 
FROM #tt
```

This returns an output like this:

[image]

What I am trying to do is this

```
SELECT
    item, LEN(item), LEFT(item, CHARINDEX(' =', item) - 1) AS v_col,
    item, LEN(item), SUBSTRING(item, CHARINDEX('=', item) + 1, LEN(item)) AS v_val
    --,v_val=SUBSTRING(item,CHARINDEX('=',item)+1,LEN(item))
FROM
    #tt
CROSS APPLY 
    dbo.SplitStrings(value)
```

But I get this error:

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function Sql Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first call to `CHARINDEX` you are searching for space followed by `=`, which does not seem to appear in your actual data.  My guess is that you are seeing this error due to this or because some column values do not have an `=` in it at all.  You could workaround by using a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT
    item,
    CASE WHEN item LIKE '%=%'
         THEN LEFT(item, CHARINDEX('=', item) - 1) END AS v_col,
    CASE WHEN item LIKE '%=%'
         THEN SUBSTRING(item, CHARINDEX('=', item) + 1, LEN(item)) END AS v_val
FROM #tt
CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings(value)
```